# Giardia infection, how long until safe beyond incubation

Tags: cats, health, parasites, infections

I picked up two wonderful Norwegian Forest Cats from the breeder two days ago. Two weeks ago they were sick with a Giardia infection, as confirmed by the breeder's vet's lab checks.

The last symptoms were seen almost 2 weeks ago, last Tuesday (5 days ago) was the last medication dose. They have not shown any signs of illness, digestion is clean and solid, they play like wild and are happy and active. No signs of illness.

I will get them tested again, but for the sake of short-term peace of mind i wanted to ask: how safe is it to assume that the parasites are gone for good? I was afraid they would be carried in, so i did not use the breeder's blanket and cat utensils, despite her recommendations. So the only way the parasites could have come in externally is via the fur, basically. They have not been shampooed or washed – not by me, nor by the breeder. (I wonder if this should have been done).

Any input is appreciated. Many thanks